# gh-pages branch doesn't have latest deployments and commits from master

Tags: reactjs, git, github, github-pages

I have `master` branch at https://github.com/arepalli-praveenkumar/shopping-cart

I'm doing **npm run deploy** in `master` branch from VS Code IDE then i notice a new deployment in gh-pages branch and able to see my react app published to https://arepalli-praveenkumar.github.io/shopping-cart/

I have made several commits in `master` and run deploy cmd now i don't find any more deployments in `gh-pages` branch or no new deployments.

Am i doing wrong ? Please help to resovle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a missing part why deployments were not available in `gh-pages` branch after **npm run deploy** in master was that I was modifying and commit/push only package.json and executing deploy command.

`npm run deploy` not considering **package.json** commit in deployment .

i had opened any **.js** or **.html** file made few changes (give space in where so that file change would be triggered for commit).

Now committed **package.json** and **.js** file together. Now **npm run deploy** able to trigger a build in `gh-pages` branch.